# Get value of radio button with onChange for javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, onchange

I have some radio buttons and I want to get their values with onChange for my function.

```
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" onchange="getRating(???)> 1
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" onchange="getRating(???)> 2
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" onchange="getRating(???)> 3
```

my function:

```
function getRating(ratingValue) {
     $.ajax({
          url: '/Rating/Create',
          type: "POST",
          data: {rating: ratingValue.value },
     success: function (data) {
          //Successmessage
          console.log(ratingValue);
     },
     error: function (xhr) {
          //Errormessage
    }
```

How can I get the value of the radio button?

Comment: @EleazarEnrique Well I shouldn't do it with jQuery and my teacher wants that I put the value of the radio button as an attribute of the function. So I need to put the value in here: getRating(here)

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  I didn't realize!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. Pretty simple.
Just added "value" in the brackets:

```
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" onchange="getRating(value)> 1
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" onchange="getRating(value)> 2
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" onchange="getRating(value)> 3
```

Answer (score 10):

One possible approach is passing `this` (an element an event is triggered on) into `getRating` as its argument. Like this:

```js
function getRating(el) {
  console.log(el.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" onchange="getRating(this)"> 1
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" onchange="getRating(this)"> 2
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" onchange="getRating(this)"> 3
```

As alternative, you can pass element's value into a function directly:

```
HTML

<input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" onchange="getRating(value)" /> 1

<!-- and so on -->

JS

function getRating(ratingValue) {
  // process the given value
}
```

... using the fact that EventHandler's Lexical Environment [contains element itself](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#getting-the-current-value-of-the-event-handler) (and therefore its properties are accessible directly, without explicit reference to `this`).

Comment: Seems like you've just posted this answer while I found out what the problem was but thanks anyway :) I tried with "this" before but then I got the input-element as value

Answer (score 2):

Just use an event listener:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[name="rating"]', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

**JSFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/59uquvfz/5/